# why Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'？

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;
using SolidWorks.Interop.swconst;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void open_swfile(string filepath, int x, string pgid)
        {
            SldWorks swApp = null;
            ModelDoc2 swAssemModleDoc = null;
            //SldWorks swApp;

            if (x == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no SolidWorks");
            }
            else if (x == 1)
            {
                System.Type swtype = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID(pgid);
                swApp = (SldWorks)System.Activator.CreateInstance(swtype);
                //swApp.Visible = true;
                swAssemModleDoc = (ModelDoc2)swApp.ActiveDoc;
            }
        }

        public static void ProcessExited()
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("SLDWORKS");

            foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                if (process.ProcessName == "SLDWORKS")
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static void DoKillOnce()
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("SLDWORKS");

            foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                if (process.ProcessName == "SLDWORKS")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        process.Kill();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void KILLSW()
        {
            if (ProcessExited())
            {
                do
                {
                    DoKillOnce();
                } while (ProcessExited());
                MessageBox.Show("Soldiworks process clean!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no process!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting errors:

> CS0103    The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context ClassLibrary2   23  Active
>   Error CS0127  Since 'Class1.ProcessExited()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression  ClassLibrary2   40  Active
>   Error CS0127  Since 'Class1.ProcessExited()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression  ClassLibrary2   43  Active
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool' ClassLibrary2   65  Active
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool' ClassLibrary2   70  Active
>   Error CS0103  The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context ClassLibrary2   71  Active
>   Error CS0103  The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context ClassLibrary2   75  Active
>
> Warning   NU1701  using“.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8”not“.NETStandard,Version=v2.1”Restore package“SolidWorks.Interop 16.10.0”。This package may not be fully compatible with the project.   ClassLibrary2   1

Comment: hi @sunne, let me know if the solution worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

`void` isn't a type, more the absence of a type.

It means that a method doesn't return a value. You are trying to return a value (true or false in this case) from a method that is declared as returning no value.

You have to specify a return type on the method if you want to return a type

```
public static bool ProcessExited() 
{
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Make the following corrections:**

> CS0103 The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context
>   ClassLibrary2 23 Active

- Right Click `Project > Add > Reference > Assemblies > System.Windows.Forms`

> Error CS0127 Since 'Class1.ProcessExited()' returns void, a return
>   keyword must not be followed by an object expression ClassLibrary2 43
>   Active

- Change return type of `ProcessExited()` from `Void` to `bool`

**Note**

You can use inbuilt property `Process.HasExited` to check the associated process has been terminated.

```
 if (process.HasExited==true)
 {
   //This process has exited, do something 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you . I'm gonna definitely give it a try... Ive been stuck on this for hours

Comment: @sunne, you can tell us how it goes